# Good Continuing Education Course in the Basics of Frequency Analysis

Tags: frequency-spectrum, soft-question

All,

Are there any good continuing education courses of length 2-3 days to give an engineer a good background in Frequency Analysis.  B&K used to teach one, but I don't think that they teach it anymore.  I am looking for something that teaches sampling, aliasing, continuous vs. discrete signals, DFT, PSD, windowing, spectral leakage, filtering, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! You mean *course over internet* ?

Comment: Preferably face-to-face.

Comment: Afaik here members like @DanBoschen or MarcusMueller , provide such DSP courses. You may contact them? Depending on where you live (for physical face-to-face) , other members could also help...

Comment: @Fat32 Thank you for the referral and the OP has reached out to me. Here is the link to the next course coming up in a few weeks for anyone in the Boston area: http://ieeeboston.org/digital-signal-processing-dsp-wireless-communications/

Comment: @DanBoschen Oh I'm glad to hear that. I've got some B&K technical documentations (from my former job, 15 years old pdfs), that might be helpful to you on **audio** things like  microphones, preamplifers, room impulse responses etc. Ethically I've never used them for anything (not even read them) but just kept them in my hdd. I can upload them to some where, for your benefit if you wish...

Comment: Oh thank you but no, ethically I wouldn’t want to do that either. But yes audio is a whole other world to me!